# Python BruteForce Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to do a Bruteforce script, so mine is working, but is also very very low.
My teacher gave me a small Shadow file and from the shadow file I have to find the original password (MD5 used here). I know that my code is working but I'm looking for tips and tricks to improve it.

```
import hashlib
import itertools




#possible characters in user password
Alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.;#@")
#minimum password value
CharLength = 6

#getting passwords and username from shadow file
with open("shadow_test", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    users = []
    passwd = []
    #getting everyline from shadow file into an array
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)
    #saving only username and passwords
    for pw in array:
        str(pw)
        r= pw.split(":")
        users.append(r[0])
        passwd.append(r[1])
    # print(users)
    # print(passwd)

    list = []
    #removing passowrd with * or !
    for mdp in passwd:
        if mdp != '*' and mdp != '!':
            str(mdp)
            list.append(mdp)
            # trying to Bruteforce
            for _ in range(12):
                passwords = (''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength))

                #print(*passwords)
                for pswd in passwords:
                    hash_object = hashlib.md5(str.encode(pswd)).hexdigest()
                    # hash_object.update(*passwords.encode('utf-8'))
                    generatedpassword = '$1$' + hash_object
                    # print(generatedpassword)

                    for compare in list:
                        for user in users:
                            #print('on cherche le Mot de passe : ' + compare +' pour ' +user)
                            #print('mot de passe MD5 généré : ' +generatedpassword)
                            #print('mot de passe clair généré : ' +pswd)


                            if generatedpassword == compare:
                                print('Le Mot de passe pour' + user + ' est : ' + pswd)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use capital letters with underscores for constants https://pep8.org/#constants
   There is no need to wrap alphabet string into parentheses:

```
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.;#@"
LENGTH = 6
```

2. Expression `str(pw)` does nothing so you can remove it. You probably meant `pw = str(pw)` but it is redundant since `pw` already is `str`
3. You do not need `array` variable at all, just iterate over input file line by line. Also, unpacking is more readable:

```
    for line in ins:
        user, password, *rest = line.split(":")
        users.append(user)
        passwd.append(password)
```

4. Since you ignore passwords `"*"` and `"!"` it is better to filter them out when reading from file.
5. Since `ins` is not used after generating `users` and `passwd` lists you do not need to place rest of code inside `with` block. Actually, the first block may look like:

```
#getting passwords and username from shadow file
with open("shadow_test", "r") as ins:
    users = []                                                         
    passwd = []
    for line in ins:
        user, password, *rest = line.split(":")
        if password not in ('*', '!'):
            users.append(user)
            passwd.append(password)
```

6. Why do you need `for _ in range(12)` loop? Just to make the program 12 times slower? Remove it.
7. Do not use names of built-in funciton names for variables, like `list`. BTW, why do you need it at all? Just iterate over all possible words and look for their hash in `passwd`:

```
passwords = (''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(ALPHABET, repeat=LENGTH))
for pswd in passwords:
    # calculate hash of pswd and if it is equal to one in passwd print it
```

8. When you compare generated hash with elements of passwd you do not need to iterate over all usernames and print them all! Actually it is better to make "password hash" -> "username" dictionary so you can check if `generatedpassword` is one of given password hashes faster (because checking that `dict` has a key generally is faster than checking each element of array):

```
with open("shadow_test", "r") as ins:
    data = dict()
    for line in ins:
        username, password, *rest = line.split(":")
        if password not in ('*', '!'):
            data[password] = username

password_hash = md5hash("qwerty")  # assume it is a function for calculating md5
if passwod_hash in data:
    print("qwerty is password of", data[password_hash])
```

9. It is probably better to remove `"$1$"` from stored records rather than add it to each calculated hash:

```
if password not in ('*', '!'):
    assert password.startswith("$1$"), "Expect password records to begin with $1$"
    data[password[3:]] = username  # remove $1$
```

So the whole solution may look like:

````
import hashlib
import itertools


def md5hash(char_sequence):
    string = ''.join(char_sequence)
    hash_object = hashlib.md5(string.encode())
    return hash_object.hexdigest()


# possible characters in user password
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.;#@"
# password length
LENGTH = 6

# getting passwords and username from shadow file
with open("shadow_test", "r") as ins:
    data = dict()  # hash -> username mapping from shadow file
    for line in ins:
        username, password, *rest = line.split(":")
        if password not in ('*', '!'):
            data[password[3:]] = username  # remove $1$

# bruteforce
for word in itertools.product(ALPHABET, repeat=LENGTH):
    generated_hash = md5hash(word)
    if generated_hash in data:
        print('The password of user', data[generated_hash], 'is:', word)
```
````